# Infragistics nested UltraWebGrid alignment issue with IE9

Tags: infragistics

I am using `Infragistics UltraWebGrid` version is 11.1.20111.1006 on MS Visual Studio 2008. I have implemented nested UltraWebGrid. Parent grid is getting rendered properly but when I click a link to view child (i.e. nested) grid, alignment of child grid's header and row gets disturbed. I am testing it on Internet Explorer 9 (IE9).

Can you suggest a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Is the issue reproducible with the latest for the moment service release 11.1.20111.2135? If so i would suggest contacting the support with a sample reproducing it.

Comment: yups, issue is still there even after installation of 11.1.20111.2135. ok i'm in touch with support team of infragistics.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend to try to add this style to the page:

```
#UltraWebGrid1_div>table>tbody>tr>td>table>colgroup>col:first-child
{
              width: 0px !important;    
}
```